# problem trying to configure xorg in debian arm system

Tags: display, arm, debian, xorg

I'm trying to get the display working with xorg an a LOGIC PD TI AM35X SOM-M2 system running debian through a NFS boot setup.  The LCD touchscreen display that I have hooked up comes up as /deb/fb0.

Here is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Device "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 16
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "omapfb"
    Option "fb" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection
```

when I run startx I get a few errors.  here's the output I get.

```
root@bsom1:~# startx
hostname: Name or service not known
xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "bsom1:0" in "add" command


X.Org X Server 1.7.7
Release Date: 2010-05-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.31-rc9 armv5tel Debian
Current Operating System: Linux bsom1 2.6.37 #1 Wed Jun 8 15:44:29 EDT 2011 armv7l
Kernel command line: console=ttyO2,115200n8 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=10.211.80.90:/home/brichmond/workdir/opt/squeeze
Build Date: 19 February 2011  03:00:40PM
xorg-server 2:1.7.7-13 (Cyril Brulebois <kibi@debian.org>)
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jan  3 21:56:11 2000
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) omapfb(0): Failed to open /dev/fb1: No such file or directory
(EE) omapfb(0): XVScreenInit failed
```

So the first thing I noticed is that x is trying to open fb1 instead of fb0.  Any incite why this is happening and how to fix this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the output of `ls -qalh /dev/fb*`

Comment: root@bsom1:~# ls -qalh /dev/fb*
    crw-rw---- 1 root video 29, 0 Jan  3 21:55 /dev/fb0